# Создание приватной комнаты в чате

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Сделал клиент-сервер чат на C#, теперь есть задача реализовать приватную комнату.

1. Как сделать вход в комнату?
2. Как сделать, чтобы сообщения от клиентов, которые в комнате, отображались только в этой комнате или как на сервере разделять эти комнаты, чтобы все комнаты и общий чат были независимые?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если комната идентифицируется своим внутренним номером, то можно сделать следующее:

1. Сопоставлять на стороне сервера:

   - каждому пользователю неупорядоченное множество номеров комнат, в которых он находится,
   - каждому сообщению — номер комнаты, в которой оно было опубликовано.
2. При появлении на сервере нового сообщения отсылать его только тем пользователям, у которых в вышеупомянутом множестве присутствует тот же номер, что и у сообщения.
3. После подключения клиента к серверу отослать первому пару «номер комнаты — дополнительные параметры комнаты (название и пр.)».